Unable to convert jsonb into row
I want the jsonb output in row format for each user. If the user has 2 subjects then 2 rows should be created for that user. In some JSON certidate would be present. Where certidate is not present createdOn should be used as certificate_date in output.
My table looks like below:-
create table rewards
(
id serial primary key,
userid varchar(50),
details jsonb
);

Details column in table has below records. Below are 3 jsons for 3 different user. Record looks like 1, Nik, JSON1valuefrombelow , 2, SAM, JSON2valuefrombelow and same for 3rd user
JSON1
[
  {
    "score": 80,
    "createdOn": 1664494754585,
    "subject": "Math"
  }  
]

JSON2
[
  {
    "score": 70,
    "certidate": 1664494754515,
    "subject": "Science"
  }  
]

JSON3
[
  {
    "score": 85,
    "certidate": 1664494754250,
    "subject": "Science"
    "score2": 85,
    "certidate2": 1664494754250,
    "subject2": "Math"
  }  
]

Output should appear in below format:-
id | userid | subject | certificate_date 

I understand that probably jsonb_array_elements can solve problem but I am even not able to see any rows for below query:-
SELECT *
FROM rewards r, 
jsonb_array_elements(r.details->'createdOn') as createdOn;



Only one of those records has the createdOn key. 2) You are not going to get id | userid | subject | certificate_date by selecting only the createdOn value. 3) jsonb_array_elements will give the output in vertical form.



Yes its a valid case where certificate date wasn't recorded, they used createdOn'. 2. I want output in tabular format. Consider each jsonb belongs to each user.  I believe with help of jsonb_array_elements we can expand that in table like structure or is there any other function available?


Even a simple query is throwing me null values in output
select details->>'score' as score from rewards;

jsonb_array_elements(r.details)->'createdOn'

All jsons looks like 1 element table, so you can change json format (if this is not real table but always one object inside) or unwind table using jsonb_array_elements
Assuming that you want to keep table inside json jsonb_array_elements function returns each table element (and in this case this is also jsonb object).
select 
  r.id, 
  r.userid, 
  elem.value->>'subject' as subject,
  coalesce(elem.value->'certidate',elem.value->'createdOn') as certificate_date
from rewards r, jsonb_array_elements(r.details) as elem

To get value from first element of a table you can use
select details->0->'createdOn' from rewards r;


id | userid | subject | certificate_date  - I am expecting output in this format. However as soon as you add subject.value->'subject' after createdOn.value->'createdOn', it throws an error

I've change table naming as it was confusing

I have elaborated question more after Details column in table has below records.

I guess we are very close. We are getting column output still in jsonb even when I am using ::varchar and subject in " ". Isnt it possible to have both field as normal varchar..

I've added cast ->> instead of ->. It returns text instead of jsonb

Yes, that works and for JSON3(where a student can have both subjects) I will provide elem.value->>'subject2' and so on and on top of that will write CTE to get output in this format id | userid | subject | certificate_date

I've added coalesce to take createdon only if there is no certidate.

You need to pass r.details (the array value) to jsonb_array_elements, not r.details->'createdOn' (which doesn't exist). It seems you are looking for
SELECT
  id,
  userid,
  details->>'subject' AS subject,
  to_timestamp(COALESCE(details->'certidate', details->'createdOn')::float/1000) AS certificate_date
FROM rewards r, 
jsonb_array_elements(r.details) as details;

